# If $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1$ is $x\mapsto x^n$, then $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}\cong\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}^{\oplus n}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1$ be the map given by $f(x)=x^n$. (I'm giving this as a concrete example, but I also care about the global picture. I.e., what happens for more general finite maps.)

The standard semicontinuity theorems should imply that $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$ is locally free, but I think that it's even globally free of rank $n$ (if $x$ is the coordinate on the domain, perhaps it even makes sense to say that $1,x,\dotsc,x^{n-1}$ is a basis). Is this true? If so, what happens for more general finite $f$?

Comment: In fact, any locally free sheaf on the affine line is free.

Comment: To complete Sasha’s comment, for a (quasi-coherent finitely generated) sheaf on the affine line, it is locally free iff it is locally flat, ie it has no torsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for simplicity all schemes are affine because what you are asking is generally a property for affine morphisms: if $$f: X \rightarrow Y$$ is a finite morphism, one might ask whether the push forward $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free?
This is precisely the case for $f$ being **finite flat**, i.e. $f$ is finite and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a flat $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}$ module.
In algebra terms: an $A$-module $M$ is finite locally free iff it is finitely presented and $A$-flat.

Note that if $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion of a proper closed subscheme, then f is finite but not flat because $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is not free but has torsion.

In your specific case, the morphism is indeed flat! Note further that a fibre over a closed $k$-point $a\neq 0$ of your morphism $f: \mathbf{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^1$ (lets say over alg. closed $k$) looks like $Spec$ of $k[t]/(t^n-a)\cong \oplus_{i<n} k t ^{i}$ which is a finite number of points. This module is indeed generated by $1,t, \dots t^{n-1}$ as a $k$-vector space. All fibres look like this except at $0$ where $f$ is ramified.
Note that finite morphisms are integral so your map $\mathcal{O}_Y=k[t] \xrightarrow{t\mapsto t^n} k[t]=f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ makes the latter finite as a $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module with basis $1,t,\dots,t^{n-1}$.

Comment: Dear @Simonsays, I am a little confused. I understand that if $f$ is finite flat, then $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free. (Perhaps overkill, but this follows from the standard semicontinuity theorems.) Now, in the simple case where $Y$ is an affine space, $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is indeed free. (By Quillen-Suslin.) I just don't understand how to make sense of the statement that $1,\dotsc,x^{n-1}$ is a basis of it (in my $x\mapsto x^n$ case). For example, if $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ is given by $x\mapsto x(1-x)$, what's a basis of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: edited the post. Quillen Suslin is only for polynomial rings over a field but I stated something more general for affine morphisms over loc. noeth. schemes. I'll think about your other question!

Comment: I think basis should again be just 1,x if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Which properties of integral morphisms you're using on the edit? Also, I don't see how your argument is more general. You affirm that if $f$ is finite flat, then $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free (but not in general free). Now, if every vector bundle in $Y$ is trivial, we win. And this is true if $Y$ is an affine space. How do you argue otherwise?

Comment: I'm confused - what do you mean by "freeness in general" on a non affine space if not locally freeness?

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space, a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $M$ is free if $M\cong\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I}$ for some index set $I$.

Comment: ok I think without knowing anything particular about the scheme in consideration, then locally free is all that you can get.